# how to stop music if application in background

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to stop my music when the user leaves the app or clicks the home button. My application plays music even if it is in the background. How can I stop the music if the user clicks the home button? If the user returns, the music is played again.
Here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.vaporv2);
    if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
//toggle off and on :
    MusicButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
    MusicButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (MusicButton.isChecked() && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();

            } else {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Activity:

**Check for two states:**

*on pause state:* When you press home button

```
 @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(mediaPlayer!=null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        }
    }
```

*on resume state:* When you come back to your screen

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(mediaPlayer!=null && !mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in Activity you can override `onResume` and `onStop` methods
and then play/pause your app.

```
       @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
        if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        }
```

Comment: This kind of actions are usually *symmetrical*. Which means that they are performed in the opposite lifecycle event. Do you start something in `onResume`? Stop it in `onPause`. Do you stop something in `onStop`? You should start it in `onStart`

Comment: `i'm trying to stop music when user leave app or click (home button) , my application plays music even if it is in the background, how i can stop music if user click home button ? If the user returns, the music is played again`- This is what the OP asked and I answered according to it though that may not be the actual functionality.